# Error when reading TFRecords with tensorflow: tensorflow.python.framework.errors.NotFoundError: FetchOutputs node ParseSingleExample/Squeeze

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I'm really new with tensorflow and I'm sure that I'm doing something wrong here. My problem is that when I'm reading records from file, code works some times, but most of the time it fails:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import time

def readFrame(inQueue, reader):
  frameWidth = int(1920/16)+1
  frameHeight = int(1080/16)+1
  frameItemsCount = frameWidth*frameHeight

  _, serialized_frame = reader.read(inQueue)
  features = tf.parse_single_example(
      serialized_frame,
      features= {
        'x'        : tf.FixedLenFeature([frameItemsCount], tf.float32)
        , 'y'        : tf.FixedLenFeature([frameItemsCount], tf.float32)
        , 'direction': tf.FixedLenFeature([frameItemsCount], tf.float32)
        # , 'force'    : tf.FixedLenFeature([frameItemsCount], tf.float32)
        # , 'sad'      : tf.FixedLenFeature([frameItemsCount], tf.float32)
      })

  return features

# pretty much copy paste from fully_connected_reader.py
def main(_):
  with tf.Graph().as_default():
    inputFramesQueue = tf.train.string_input_producer(["tfrecords.out"], num_epochs=100)
    reader = tf.TFRecordReader()

    init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()
    sess = tf.Session()
    sess.run(init_op)
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)

    try:
      step = 0
      while not coord.should_stop() and step < 3:
        start_time = time.time()
        frameDict = readFrame(inputFramesQueue, reader)
        print(frameDict)
        frame = sess.run([
          frameDict['x']
          , frameDict['y']
          , frameDict['direction'] 
          # , frameDict['force'] 
          # , frameDict['sad']
        ])
        print(frame[2])

        duration = time.time() - start_time
        if step % 100 == 0: print('Step %d: (%.3f sec)' % (step, duration))
        step += 1
    except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
      print('Done training for %d epochs, %d steps.' % (FLAGS.num_epochs, step))
    finally:
      coord.request_stop()

    coord.join(threads)
    sess.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  tf.app.run()
```

For example when I run it these are two different outputs I'm getting:

```
(venv) bash-3.2$ python src/readframes.py
{'x': <tf.Tensor 'ParseSingleExample/Squeeze_x:0' shape=(8228,) dtype=float32>, 'direction': <tf.Tensor 'ParseSingleExample/Squeeze_direction:0' shape=(
8228,) dtype=float32>, 'y': <tf.Tensor 'ParseSingleExample/Squeeze_y:0' shape=(8228,) dtype=float32>}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mikaelle/Projects/Omat/tensorflow-grouping/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 715, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "/Users/mikaelle/Projects/Omat/tensorflow-grouping/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 697, in _run_fn
    status, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 66, in __exit__
    next(self.gen)
  File "/Users/mikaelle/Projects/Omat/tensorflow-grouping/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors.py", line 450, in raise_ex
ception_on_not_ok_status
    pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors.NotFoundError: FetchOutputs node ParseSingleExample/Squeeze_y:0: not found

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src/readframes.py", line 62, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/Users/mikaelle/Projects/Omat/tensorflow-grouping/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 30, in run
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
  File "src/readframes.py", line 44, in main
    , frameDict['direction']
  File "/Users/mikaelle/Projects/Omat/tensorflow-grouping/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 372, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/Users/mikaelle/Projects/Omat/tensorflow-grouping/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 636, in _run
    feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
  File "/Users/mikaelle/Projects/Omat/tensorflow-grouping/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 708, in _do_run
    target_list, options, run_metadata)
  File "/Users/mikaelle/Projects/Omat/tensorflow-grouping/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 728, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors.NotFoundError: FetchOutputs node ParseSingleExample/Squeeze_y:0: not found
(venv) bash-3.2$

(venv) bash-3.2$ python src/readframes.py
{'y': <tf.Tensor 'ParseSingleExample/Squeeze_y:0' shape=(8228,) dtype=float32>, 'direction': <tf.Tensor 'ParseSingleExample/Squeeze_direction:0' shape=(
8228,) dtype=float32>, 'x': <tf.Tensor 'ParseSingleExample/Squeeze_x:0' shape=(8228,) dtype=float32>}
[ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
Step 0: (0.014 sec)
{'y': <tf.Tensor 'ParseSingleExample_1/Squeeze_y:0' shape=(8228,) dtype=float32>, 'direction': <tf.Tensor 'ParseSingleExample_1/Squeeze_direction:0' sha
pe=(8228,) dtype=float32>, 'x': <tf.Tensor 'ParseSingleExample_1/Squeeze_x:0' shape=(8228,) dtype=float32>}
[ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
{'y': <tf.Tensor 'ParseSingleExample_2/Squeeze_y:0' shape=(8228,) dtype=float32>, 'direction': <tf.Tensor 'ParseSingleExample_2/Squeeze_direction:0' sha
pe=(8228,) dtype=float32>, 'x': <tf.Tensor 'ParseSingleExample_2/Squeeze_x:0' shape=(8228,) dtype=float32>}
[ 0.          2.24240255  2.24240255 ...,  0.          0.          0.        ]
(venv) bash-3.2$
```

Somehow it seems that file cannot be accessed when items are tried to be fetched from there...

Answer (score 0):

I got rid of that error by sleeping a while after starting threads and before starting to read records.

```
threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)
time.sleep(1)
```

If I added sleep, before starting threads, it had no effect... My best guess about what is happening is that there could be some read ahead buffer which is filled by queue thread, but parsing the data is not waiting that buffer has enough data before starting to read it...

I still believe that I'm doing something wrong here. Even that after adding that sleep it seems that I'm not able to read data faster than its being served.